# Flask with Backbone.js REST API

Tags: json, rest, backbone.js, flask

`Model.save()` in backbone.js sends the model data as POST to server as a JSON encoded string. Its just a string and not `variable=jsonString` as in a normal POST request. So I cant access it in Flask as `request.form.get('variable')`. Where should i be editing code? Can Flask deal such requests? Can Backbone.js send data like a normal post request and not as a JSON encoded string?

Can provide more info if required.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With Backbone the request Content-Type header is automatically set to 'application/json' (unless you've enabled emulateJSON), so Flask should automatically parse the JSON and make it available through the request object.

```
@app.route('/some_route', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def some_route():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        """ json available through request.json """
```

http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#flask.Request.json

Comment: Can I access it like  `request.json['username']` or `request.json.username` or do i need to parse json in some other way ?